# Is post-order traversal == bottom-up traversal and pre-order traversal == top-down traversal?

Tags: algorithm, tree, language-agnostic, traversal, tree-traversal

Would it be right to say post-order traversal of a tree should be used to do a bottom-up traversal whereas a pre-order traversal should be used to do a top-down traversal of a binary tree?

This has been true in all the examples that I have encountered, so I just wanted to confirm.  There are some problems for which it is intuitive to start from the leaves (at the bottom).  Can we use post-order traversal to solve them (and vice versa)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. While `post-order traversal` and `pre-order traversal` have clear definition, `bottom-up traversal` or `top-down traversal` terms might be interpreted by different ways, they are not generally accepted for binary trees. If anybody uses last terms for trees, exact meaning depends on context.

Look at the picture from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal):

[image]

Does pre-order traversal here look like `top-down traversal`? Or post-order likes `bottom-up traversal`? Seems no.

Perhaps you want to consider BFS methods to get [level order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search_/_level_order)

Comment: Does pre-order traversal here look like top-down traversal? - Well, but aren't we going from the root (at the top) to the leaves (at the bottom)?  I am not saying about it being a top-down traversal in the _traditional_ sense - I mean it more like, things (distance vector, values, etc.) can be passed from the root (top) to the leaves (bottom).

Comment: Yes, we can say that pre-order is more top-down than other traversals.

Comment: That answers my doubt!  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

No. And actually the terms ***bottom-up / top-down*** are generally used for graph, but for trees, it's sort of used as explained below:

- **Preorder traversal:** Parents are visited before
  children and siblings are visited in left-to-right order (might be successively but not always).
- **Postorder traversal:** Children are visited before
  parents and siblings are visited in left-to-right order.
- **Top-down traversal:** nodes are visited in the order of non-decreasing depth. Which is basically level-order traversal
- **Bottom-up traversal:** This is exactly reverse of top-down traversal